# Как найти цифру 0 в в заданном числе JAVA

Tags: java, строки, сортировка, if

Нужно найти в заданном с клавиатуры шестизначном числе, цифры 0.

Каким способом это можно сделать?

Пробывал вот таким методом, переводил (int) в строку и по строчно хотел найти 0. Но он вывел ошибку при попытке ввода 0 в любом случае ввода (number).

```
int number = in.nextInt();
String test = String.valueOf(number);

int a = test.charAt(0);
if(a == 48) { a = 0; }
```

Comment: Глупо принимать из потока как число, если собираешься там искать как в тексте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
char[] userInputCharArray = sc.nextLine().toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < userInputCharArray.length; i++) {
    if (userInputCharArray[i]=='0') System.out.println(i);
}
```

В консоль получите номера позиций 0 в заданном числе

Comment: Спасибо, этот метод мне помог. Вопрос решен

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++){
     if (test.charAt(i) == '0') { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 находим первое вхождение символа
 */

/**
 *
 * @author vvm
 */
public class FindSymbol {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = in.nextInt();

        String test;
        test = Integer.toString(number);

        System.out.println("Полученная строка "+test);

        //indexOf(String str) - поиск первого вхождения подстроки
        char sybmol = '0'; // символ который ищем
        int inx;
        inx = test.indexOf(sybmol); // первое вхождение символа начиная с 0-вой позиции
        System.out.println("Первое вхождение  "+inx); // 
    }
}
```

Если нужно найти все вхождения символов, то перебираете их в цикле и заносите позиции символов в отдельный массив. Только счетчик полученного массива будет отличаться от того, который перебираете.

Comment: Спасибо, буду иметь этот вариант в виду в дальнейшем. Но вопрос уже решен.